Distance to Eiffel Tower with glassball
I'm working on a problem involving a glass ball that forms an upside-down image of the Eiffel Tower. Here is the picture:

The glass ball has a diameter of $9.5$ cm and can be treated as a thin lens with a focal length of $7.0$ cm for rays close to the axis. The photo was taken with a cell phone camera, and the small camera lens is located approximately $30$ cm from the center of the glass ball.
My task is to estimate how far the photo was taken from the Eiffel Tower using two different methods:
Using the image formed in the glass ball
Without using the glass ball (directly estimating based on the size of the Eiffel Tower in the photo)
I'm also supposed to compare the results from both methods. I’ve tried solving it with the thin lens equation, but I’m struggling to get meaningful results.
The friend of mine who took the picture already told me that the distance is about $ 200 $ m, but I am not able to identify it myself mathematically.
I was thinking that using similar triangles in the glass ball might help, but I’m not confident in my approach, since I don’t know how to start. I also thought about the law $ \frac{n_1}{s} + \frac{n_2}{s‘} = \frac{n_2 - n_1}{r}  $, but I’m uncertain on that.
Has anyone tackled something similar or have any ideas on how to proceed with both methods? Any guidance would be appreciated! Also, if you have advice on where my lens equation might be going wrong, I’d love some help there too.

International Physics Olympiad 2025

I think the issue is that you are using the thin lens approximation when a sphere is very far from a thin lens. The thin lens equation assumes the width of the lens ($d$) is negligible compared to the radii of curvature for the lens faces. For a sphere, $d$ is twice the radius of curvature, so it is not negligible.
If you use the lens maker's equation instead of the thin lens approximation, you get a better estimate for the focal length. For a sphere, $R = R_1 = -R_2$ and the width of the lens is $d = 2R$. Using these values, the lens maker's equation for a sphere simplifies to:
$$ F = \frac{Rn}{2(n-1)},$$
where $n$ is the refractive index of the glass. This result is $n$ times larger than the thin lens approximation, so it can make quite a big difference. I assume you know the refractive index because you would have needed it for the thin lens approximation. Once you have a better idea of the focal length, it is not too difficult to figure out the magnification from there and figure out the distances.
A spherical lens does not produce a perfect focus, so the focus is always going to be a sort of average figure.
If you still have the glass sphere, you can try focusing the sun on as small a spot as possible on a piece of paper (if the paper catches fire, you are at the right distance), and the focal length is then the distance from the centre of the sphere to the paper.
